# How to add drop shadow only for the right side?

Tags: ios, uiview, dropshadow

I am adding the drop shadow like this.

```
vwVertical=[[UIView alloc] init];
[vwVertical setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
vwVertical.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
vwVertical.layer.shadowColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:32/255 green:59/255 blue:90/255 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
vwVertical.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(5, 0);
vwVertical.layer.shadowOpacity=0.12;
vwVertical.layer.shadowRadius=6.5;
[vwBlock addSubview:vwVertical];
```

But this is adding shadow 3 sides. How can I add just to right side.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to inset the view's bounds on `top` - `left` - `bottom`, and use the [shadow path](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410771-shadowpath).

```
vwVertical=[[UIView alloc] init];
// Create edge insets
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
// Create rect with inset and view's bounds
CGRect shadowPathOnlyIncludingRight = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(vwVertical.bounds, contentInsets);
// Apply it on the layer's shadowPath property
vwVertical.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowPathOnlyIncludingRight].CGPath;

[vwVertical setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
vwVertical.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
vwVertical.layer.shadowColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:32/255 green:59/255 blue:90/255 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
vwVertical.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(5, 0);
vwVertical.layer.shadowOpacity=0.12;
vwVertical.layer.shadowRadius=6.5;
```

Comment: But the right side is missing shadow for the 10 pixels on top and bottom..

Comment: @AlexandreG i have updated my answer. It is strange, when i have initially answered, i was not facing the problem u just reported.

Comment: But now the shadow is not only for the right side. I've copy pasted the above code, just making the shadow opacity higher so it's more obvious to the eye: http://www.goloskok.com/u/image-6UQ1XEYirw.png

Comment: @AlexandreG that was what the original question was. how to drop shadow only on the right side.

Comment: Exactly. And in the screenshot (and in your code) it's clearly NOT only for the right side

Comment: I must argue that your implementation is wrong. I could attach screenshots too to support my claim that my code is right. But we are adults i suppose, so i just take you downvote, and wish you a great day!